# Json parse to HashMap<ArrayList<>> throwing StackOverflowError in Libgdx?

Tags: java, json, parsing, libgdx, stack-overflow

My Json is:

```
{
    "objects":{
        "apple":[
            {"x":3, "y":5},
            {"x":6, "y":9}
        ],
        "car":[
            {"x":7, "y":9},
            {"x":5, "y":8}
        ]
     }
 }
```

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ClassA{
    public Integer x, y;
}

public class ClassB{
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<ClassA>> objects; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Json json = new Json();

    ClassB classB = json.fromJson(ClassB.class, "{\n" +
            "            \"objects\":{\n" +
            "                \"apple\":[\n" +
            "                    {\"x\":3, \"y\":5},\n" +
            "                    {\"x\":6, \"y\":9}\n" +
            "                ],\n" +
            "                \"car\":[\n" +
            "                    {\"x\":7, \"y\":9},\n" +
            "                    {\"x\":5, \"y\":8}\n" +
            "                ]\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        }");

    System.out.println(json.toJson(classB));
}
```

I use "Libgdx", "json.fromJson" is works fine and when i call "json.toJson(classB)" an exception throws:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter$OutputType.quoteValue(JsonWriter.java:187)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:88)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:574)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:290)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:580)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:290)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:580)
...
```

When i change **"ArrayList"** to **String(etc)** from **HashMap** in **ClassB** the code works fine.

So why an exception is thowing when i use "ArrayList" and how can i parse my json to ClassB instance?

Comment: judging from your code you found an actual bug in the toJson function. I would submit an issue on github for this. In the meantime. I would recommend just switching to gson, it works virtually the same.

Comment: @p.streef can you paste the issue link here for follow the solution? thanks

Comment: Issue in Libgdx github https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in the comments.

Post the libGDX bug as a new issue [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues).

add this to your build.gradle dependencies (to the core project if you use the default structure):

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
```

Initialize a Gson object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

And use the from and to json functions:

```
String json = gson.toJson(classB);
```

and

```
ClassB classB = gson.fromJson(json,ClassB.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the StackOverflowException itself is a bug.

The libGDX' JSON class expects class type information in certain places, if it can't deduce the type by itself. In this regard it is much less tolerant than other, much larger libraries such as Gson.

see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON#writing-object-graphs

The easiest fix in your example is to write your ClassA instances as:

```
"    {\"class\": \"net.your.package.ClassA\", \"x\":3, \"y\":5},\n"
```

The class name can be shortened, see Json.setElementType().

In general, as a best practice, for prototyping I recommend the opposite to your approach. Create the structure in code, then write to JSON to see how libGDX "perceives" your data structure, then read back from JSON to verify the output.

Side note: for most cases its recommended to use the libGDX containers, `ObjectMap<>` and `Array<>` in your example. Also, ClassA members can probably be `int` instead of `Integer` to avoid auto-boxing.